# VS2013, how to set to remember previous file exclusions in TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, tfs

Any ideas?

I am running on local mode workspace. This is very annoying telling TFS to exclude all my project settings files every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a .[tfignore](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-files-server) file to define files and folders that shouldn't be tracked by source control.